# How do I vectorize this function?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, vectorization, fuzzy-comparison

I have a function which utilizes `jaro_winkler` and I want to vectorize it. The function is given below:

```
def check_client(name):
    name = re.sub('\W+', ' ', name)
    name = re.sub('\*', '', name)
    
    for i in client_list:
        x = textdistance.jaro_winkler(i, name)
        if x > 0.93:
            return 'Yes'
    return 'No'
```

And I tried applying this function on a column in a dataframe by:

```
df_distinct['client'] = df_distinct['name'].apply(check_client)
```

I haven't really explored anything just yet but it would be great to have an input about this. Thank you!

Comment: You probably can't vectorize this, using a list comprehension instead of apply would be marginally more efficient though